# Visual Studio 2015 publish doesn't create .compiled files in bin folder on first publish

Tags: visual-studio-2015, publish

We have various projects that we deploy after running the publish tool built into VS2015 Professional Update 1.

Most of the projects were originally built on previous versions of VS, and have been upgraded as we upgraded versions of VS.

When we publish the projects the first time, the .compiled files are not created in the "Target location". All other files are there.

We then copy/ftp the published project's bin folder to the target location on the server, and get an error on loading the site up. When we check the bin folder, there are no .compiled tiles where they should be.

[BIN folder showing files from 1st and 2nd publish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIwUA.png)

If we then publish the project without changing any of the publish settings a second time, everything compiles and there is no problem when we copy the project to the server.

[Publish settings for project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05XcD.png)

Does anyone know how to sort this problem out?

Any and all help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea if anyone out there has had this problem, but for me, it looks like the problem has gone away with the application of Update 3 for VS 2015 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by checking the `Precompile during publishing` option on the `Publish -> Settings` screen.

[image]